# C: pointers for creating a hash map to store strings using chaining

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, hash

Just for fun and practice, I'm trying to implement a hash map to store strings using C.  For some reason it works for certain strings and not others, and I am curious if my structure seems logical?  I think the problem might be how I am allocating memory, but am not sure, so if anyone might be able to tell me whether my general approach is correct or if I am failing to understand something about pointers, I would really appreciate it!

Basically there is a hash map struct with a member that is an array of pointers to linked list nodes, and the header file code is as follows:

```
#ifndef DataStructures_hash_map_h
#define DataStructures_hash_map_h

#define INITIAL_HASHMAP_CAPACITY 5
#define INITIAL_TABLE_STRING_LENGTH 40
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

// linked list node struct
struct ll_string_node { 
    char* value;
    struct ll_string_node* next;
};

struct hash_map {
    struct ll_string_node** table;
    int size;
    int capacity;
};

struct hash_map* hm_build_map() {
    struct hash_map* new_map = malloc(sizeof(struct hash_map));
    new_map->table = malloc(sizeof(struct ll_string_node)*INITIAL_HASHMAP_CAPACITY);
    new_map->size = 0;
    new_map->capacity = INITIAL_HASHMAP_CAPACITY;
    return new_map;
}

int hm_hash_me(char* value, int capacity) {
    unsigned long long int hashcode = 0;
    for (int i = 0; value[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        hashcode = hashcode*31 + value[i];
    }
    return hashcode % capacity;
}

int hm_put(char* value, struct hash_map** my_map) {
    struct ll_string_node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct ll_string_node));
    int hashcode = 0;
    if (new_node) {
        new_node->value = malloc(sizeof(char)*INITIAL_TABLE_STRING_LENGTH);
        if (new_node->value) {
            new_node->next = NULL;
            strcpy(new_node->value, value); //value is now stored in new_node->value
            hashcode = hm_hash_me(value, (*my_map)->capacity);
            if ((*my_map)->table[hashcode] == NULL) {
                (*my_map)->table[hashcode] = new_node;
            } else {
                new_node->next = (*my_map)->table[hashcode];
                (*my_map)->table[hashcode] = new_node;
            }
            (*my_map)->size++;
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }

    } else {
        return 0;
    }

}

struct ll_string_node* hm_get(char* value, struct hash_map* my_map) {
    int hashcode = hm_hash_me(value, my_map->capacity);
    while (my_map->table[hashcode] != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(my_map->table[hashcode]->value, value) == 0) {
            printf("%s\t", my_map->table[hashcode]->value);
            return my_map->table[hashcode];
        } else {
            printf("%s\t", my_map->table[hashcode]->value);
            my_map->table[hashcode] = my_map->table[hashcode]->next;
        }
    }
    return my_map->table[hashcode];
} 

#endif
```

then the main.c file is as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "hash_map.h"
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    struct hash_map* my_map = hm_build_map();
    hm_put("law and order", &my_map); //hashcode of 1
    hm_put("Batman", &my_map); //
    hm_put("CSI Miami", &my_map);
    hm_put("The Flash", &my_map);
    hm_get("Snoopy", my_map);
    hm_get("Pinwheel", my_map); //causes program to crash
    hm_get("Snoopy", my_map);
    hm_get("law and order", my_map);
    hm_get("Snoopy", my_map);
    hm_get("CSI Miami", my_map);
    hm_get("Snoopy", my_map); //causes program to crash
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A bunch of code isn't much of help. You must be more specific with your problem. Which function fails and with what input. Your pointer knowledge seems ok.

Comment: @ γηράσκω δ' αεί πολλά διδασκόμε Thank you very much for responding.  the hm_get fails on the condition: strcmp(my_map->table[hashcode]->value, value), and says "BAD_ACCESS". I am storing TV show names.  Some strings that are not in the array always fail (e.g.,"Pinwheel"), and other strings (e.g. "Snoopy") that are in the array fail depending on what order I get them relative to other strings. That is I think the hm_get string function might be modifying the table, even though I am not passing a double pointer to the function.

Comment: Maybe you are corrupting somewhere the header of the linked list. Can you provide the rest of the code to test it myself?

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε Thanks you very much, I have added the full code.  I think you are right, because for some of the tables indexes the last item in the linked list should point to null, but instead it points to something where there is no value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested your code but an obvious error is in *hm_build_map()*. `table` is a pointer to a pointer to a struct, so

```
new_map->table = malloc(sizeof(struct ll_string_node)*INITIAL_HASHMAP_CAPACITY);
```

is wrong. First you have to allocate 5(INITIAL_HASHMAP_CAPACITY) pointers eg INITIAL_HASHMAP_CAPACITY * 4 bytes

```
new_map->table = malloc(sizeof(int)*INITIAL_HASHMAP_CAPACITY);
```

and then allocate memory for each of these pointers

```
for(i = 0; i < INITIAL_HASHMAP_CAPACITY; i++)
{
    new_map->table[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct ll_string_node));
}
```

**EDIT**

The part of allocating memory for the 5 pointers is not necessary as they are the headers. Just set them to `NULL`

```
for(i = 0; i < INITIAL_HASHMAP_CAPACITY; i++)
{
    new_map->table[i] = NULL;
}
```

Change *hm_get*:

```
struct ll_string_node* hm_get(char* value, struct hash_map* my_map) {
    struct ll_string_node *temp;

    int hashcode = hm_hash_me(value, my_map->capacity);
    temp = my_map->table[hashcode]; //<- here use a temp so you dont move the header
    while (temp != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(temp->value, value) == 0) {
            printf("%s\t", temp->value);
            return temp;
        } else {
            printf("%s\t", temp->value);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
    return temp;
```

}

**EDIT2**

Initially

```
node0  -> node1 -> node3 ->....   
  ^   
  |   
my_map->table[hashcode]
```

After *my_map->table[hashcode] = my_map->table[hashcode]->next;*

```
node0  -> node1 -> node3 ->....  
           ^   
           |  
  my_map->table[hashcode]
```

You lost your header!

```
node0  -> node1 -> node3 ->....   
^ ^   
| |   
| temp
my_map->table[hashcode]
```

After *temp = temp->next;*

```
node0  -> node1 -> node3 ->....  
^           ^   
|           |  
|           temp
my_map->table[hashcode]
```

Everything ok!

Comment: Thanks, I changed this but unfortunately I still get the same error of "Bad Access"on the "while (my_map->table[hashcode]->value  != NULL)" condition.  I think that one problem is that when I put a string into the array, I am checking if the address contained in that table index is null, and sometimes it is not, so when I add the element to the beginning of the linked list, the end of the list points to something that isn't there. Not quite sure how to fix this though.

Comment: thanks, I just set the pointers to null, but it seems it still doesn't work.  I allocate the table as follows: new_map->table = malloc(sizeof(int)*INITIAL_HASHMAP_CAPACITY); then I set each element of the table to NULL as in your edit.  But I still get the BAD_ACCESS error.

Comment: By the way, since table is an array of struct pointers should I use, malloc(sizeof(struct ll_string_node*)*INITIAL_HASHMAP_CAPACITY);

Comment: Thank you!!! I have spent so much time trying to figure this out, and now, thanks to you it is working.  I really, really appreciate it.  I didn't know that doing it the way I was doing it would move the header, as I thought since I had only passed in a single pointer an not a double pointer I couldn't move it. But I guess it was for some reason.  Perhaps because table is a double pointer?  Thank you once again!